# How to automaticaly delete all cookies BUT cookies from specific white-listed websites in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Firefox has the ability to make all cookies session only with exceptions, so you can choose some websites to store cookies and all the other cookies are deleted when you quit Firefox.

How can it be done in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the correct answer is that Chrome does not have this feature. The better way I've found until now to clear all the cookies but cookies from some specific websites is using CCleaner. You can select in the options which websites' cookies you want to preserve, and run CCleaner from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

The [Vanilla Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gieohaicffldbmiilohhggbidhephnjj) can do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Visit `chrome://settings/content/cookies`.
2. Turn on “Keep local data only until you quit your browser”.
3. In the **Allow** section, click the **Add** button and enter each website you want to save and enter it one of these forms:

   - `google.com`
   - `[*.]google.com`
   - `https://[*.]google.com`
   - `https://[*.]google.com:443`

Done!

Answer (score 0):

For others that may be looking for a solution, you can also use this open source extension [Cookie AutoDelete](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-autodelete/fhcgjolkccmbidfldomjliifgaodjagh) that allows you to set domain based rules and choose per domain whether to delete cookies upon tab close or browser start.