# How can I keep persistent cookies from certain domains only?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

This question is similar [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/26689/how-do-i-tell-firefox-to-only-keep-persistent-cookies-from-sites-i-want) which covers Firefox, but I want to know how to do it in Chrome:

I want Chrome to clear cookies from all sites accept those from certain domains. In the **Cookies** section of the **Content Settings* I've made following selections:

```
(*) Allow local data to be set (recommended)
( ) Allow local data to be set for the current session only
( ) Block sites from setting any data
[ ] Block third-party cookies and site data
[x] Clear cookies and other sites and plug-in data when I close my browser
```

After logged in to my preferred website(s), I find the required domains listed when I click at *All cookies and site data*. Let's say, I find some cookies for `mysite.com`and `www.mysite.com`. Now I click at *Manage exceptions* and enter these items:

```
Hostname Pattern                   Behavior
-------------------------------------------
mysite.com                         Allow
www.mysite.com                     Allow
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work, because when I close Chrome and reopen it, all cookies are gone, even those from the configured `mysite.com` hosts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automaticaly delete all cookies BUT cookies from specific white-listed websites in Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/173004/how-to-automaticaly-delete-all-cookies-but-cookies-from-specific-white-listed-we)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do what you want without extensions, and ended up installing *Vanilla Cookie Manager* extension (I cannot see its page today, but if you [search for it](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/vanilla%20cookie%20manager), it shows at the top).

Once you configure it, it adds a small icon to your address bar that allows you to quickly add the current site to a whitelist.

Answer (score 4):

From Chrome's [help](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95647) docs, you need to prepend the domain name with [*.]domain.com to match all subdomains (which includes www). So for your example:

```
Hostname Pattern                   Behavior
-------------------------------------------
[*.]mysite.com                     Allow
```